# Frameworks for tracking end user usage/analytics for Microsoft asp.net

Tags: asp.net

I would like to have framework for tracking web site/page usage within company firewalls on asp.net platform.

Want to track hits and integrate with particular feature within an application to understand end user usage (i.e. log particular actions of users in addition to simple page count type analytics)

I have yet to find a framework to do this with asp.net/iis7 internal to a company (i.e. not google analytics)

thx

Answer (score 0):

If you don't need anything too fancy, as in number of visits to urls, and you've got the clearance to install perl/CGI scripts, you could use [awstats](http://awstats.sourceforge.net/). It isn't bad for what it is and has the advantage of being free.

If you are down to spend some $$$ or you really need google analytics, you can host your own by [purchasing an urchin license](http://www.google.com/urchin/).

Comment: I am looking for a .net solution to this problem.  I am surprised that there are not a number of options.  What am I missing?

Comment: It was a problem that was largely solved before .NET existed . . .